# Join three tables like the given example

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

```
     A                         B                   C
id col1 col2         id   col3  col4      sno   id  col5  col6
1  arv   12           1     xcv  sdf       1    2   qwe   arv 
2  qwe   34                                2    2   zxc   cvb
3  asd   23
```

I want the output to be like

```
id    col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6
1     arv       12       xcv     sdf
2     qwe       34                        qwe       arv
3     qwe       34                        zxc       cvb
```

What should I do to get the above result?

B id is foreign key to A id. sno is primary key in C . C id is foreign key to A id.

Comment: How do the tables relate to each other?  Is B.id a foreign key to A (same for C.id)?

Comment: are you sure that C id is not related to A and B?

Comment: If `C.id` is not related to `A` and `B` then how is `C` related to the other tables?

Comment: Does `C.sno` relate to either `A` or `B`?

Comment: Looks to me like c.Id is related to a.Id and b.Id.. And sno is some kind of sequence number

Comment: sorry!! confused a bit. Check the question now.

Comment: I knew that's where we were headed... just like everyone else did!

Comment: Where does `id` of the output come from? Is it just a sequence number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT @id := @id + 1 AS id,
       A.col1, A.col2, B.col3, B.col4, C.col5, C.col6       
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN C ON A.id = C.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id := 0) AS var
WHERE B.id IS NOT NULL OR C.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY A.id, C.sno
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67532/1)

Answer (score 0):

Given that C is related to A

```
SELECT A.id, A.col1, A.col2, B.col3, B.col4, C.col5, c.Col6
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.id = A.id
```